# Extjs4 grid's paging functionality is not working

Tags: grid, extjs4, paging

i am working in extjs4. I am adding paging functionality to grid. I am having my grid view code as-
allQuestionPapers.js

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.       ', {
            extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
            alias : 'widget.paperlist',
            id : 'paperId',
            store : 'qb.QbqnsStore',
            border : false,
            // height:autoheight,
            width : 600,
            autoScroll : true,
            columns : [{
                        text : 'date',
                        width : 200,
                        dataIndex : 'createDate'
                    }, {
                        text : 'QuestionpaperNo',
                        width : 200,
                        dataIndex : 'questionPaperNo'
                    }, {
                        text : 'Marks',
                        width : 200,
                        dataIndex : 'obtainMarks'
                    }],
            dockedItems : [{
                        xtype : 'pagingtoolbar',
                        id : 'pagingtoolbarId',
                        pageSize : 10,
                        dock : 'bottom',
                        displayInfo : true

                    }]
        });
```

And in controller i am dynamically creating store and binding it to grid.For this i had written code as-

```
getAllPapers:function()
    {   
        var paperlistStore=Ext.create('Balaee.store.qb.QbqnsStore',
            {autoLoad: {params:{start:0, limit:10}}});
        proxy= paperlistStore.getProxy();
        Ext.apply(proxy.api,{
            read:'index.php/QuestionBank/qbpaper/getUserAllQuestionPaper'
        });


        Ext.apply(proxy.reader,{
            type:'json',
            root:'questions'
        });

        Ext.apply(proxy.writer,{
            type:'json',
            root:'data'
        });

        var answers = '{"data":[';
        answers = answers + '{"userId":1}';
        answers =answers+']}';
        console.log(answers);


        paperlistStore.load({
            params:{
                data: answers
            },
            callback: function(records,operation,success){
                console.log(records);
                console.log("Successfully data send");
            },
            scope:this
        });

        var temp2=Ext.getCmp('QbqnsResultmainId');
        temp2.removeAll();

        var worldChaptor1 =Ext.create('Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.allQuestionPapers');
        var resultView = Ext.getCmp('pagingtoolbarId');
        console.log(resultView);
        resultView.bindStore(paperlistStore); 
        temp2.add(worldChaptor1);
}
```

All this is working correctly.But grid is showing only 3 records per page instead of showing 25 records as per grid's paging function's dispaly message"displaying 1-25 of 280". So what changes i need to make in order to diaplay such 25 record per page.